# Scraper not finding pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider written as below, but it doesn't seem to be getting to the function `parse`. Could someone take a quick look and let me know if I'm missing something. Am I implementing the SgmlLinkExtractor properly?

The spider should pick out all the links from the left sidebar, create a request from them, then parse the next page for a facebook link. It should also do this for other pages as specified in the SgmlLinkExtractor. At the moment, the spider is running, but not parsing any pages.

```
class PrinzSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "prinz"
    allowed_domains = ["prinzwilly.de"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.prinzwilly.de/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(
                allow=(r'veranstaltungen-(.*)', ),
            ),
            callback='parse'
            ),
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        startlinks = hxs.select("//ul[@id='mainNav2']/li/a")
        print startlinks
        for link in startlinks:
            giglink = link.select('@href').extract()
            item = GigItem()
            item['gig_link'] = giglink
            request = Request(item['gig_link'], callback='parse_gig_page')
            item.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse_gig_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = response.meta['item']
        gig_content = hxs.select("//div[@class='n']/table/tbody").extract()
        fb_link = re.findall(r'(?:www.facebook.com/)(.*)', gig_content)
        print '********** FB LINK ********', fb_link
        return item
```

EDIT ****

`settings.py`

```
BOT_NAME = 'gigscraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['gigscraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'gigscraper.spiders'

ITEM_PIPLINES = ['gigscraper.pipelines.GigscraperPipeline']
```

`items.py`

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class GigItem(Item):
    gig_link = Field()
```

`pipelines.py`

```
class GigscraperPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print 'here I am in the pipeline'
        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

- `extract()` returns a list, you are missing `[0]`
- Request's callback should not be a string, use `self.parse_gig_page`

Here's the modified code (working):

```
import re
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class GigItem(Item):
    gig_link = Field()


class PrinzSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "prinz"
    allowed_domains = ["prinzwilly.de"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.prinzwilly.de/"]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'veranstaltungen-(.*)',)), callback='parse'),)

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        startlinks = hxs.select("//ul[@id='mainNav2']/li/a")
        for link in startlinks:
            item = GigItem()
            item['gig_link'] = link.select('@href').extract()[0]
            yield Request(item['gig_link'], callback=self.parse_gig_page, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_gig_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = response.meta['item']
        gig_content = hxs.select("//div[@class='n']/table/tbody").extract()[0]
        fb_link = re.findall(r'(?:www.facebook.com/)(.*)', gig_content)
        print '********** FB LINK ********', fb_link
        return item
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm still getting nothing. I'm not getting the print statements... nothing. It seems that it's not finding the first url.

Comment: @puffin that's strange, it works for me. Is it a part of scrapy project? If yes, show your settings (edit the question and paste there).

Comment: You should avoid overriding the `parse()` method when using `CrawlSpider`. See [this warning from the Scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules). Rename it to `parse_page()` or something

Comment: @paul t Thanks, Paul. I've tried that and still, it is parsing 0 pages.

Comment: @puffin, I put the scrapy files on Cloud9 IDE. Have a look at https://c9.io/redapple/scrapy_tutorial : look under `scrapy_tutorial/gigscraper`; it contains @alecxe suggestions, I renamed `parse` to `parse_page` to follow good practice. The spider runs fine and collects 39 items. (in the terminal at the bottom, `cd gigscraper/; scrapy crawl prinz`)